# Flexslider breaks jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

When I remove the script "flexslider.js", the accordion works, but the slider disappears. When I leave it, only the slider works, but when I click on the accordion points, the page just moves down. Can you please tell me what to do :( I have jQuery FlexSlider v2.6.2 and simple panel-group in Bootstrap 3

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    directionNav: false,
    pauseOnAction: false,
});

var containerPosition = $('.container').offset();
var positionPad = containerPosition.left + 15;

$('#slider').find('.caption').css({
    left: positionPad + 'px',
    marginTop: '-' + $('.caption').height() / 2 + 'px'
});
```

from main script.js

[Here is my github](https://github.com/neosheps/sunmartur)

Thank you!

Comment: This work! Thank you very much!

Comment: @NeoSheps next time please try to find the solution to your problem before you ask a question.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski Sorry, im really tried, but my english is not good, so i did not understand what was being said in these question before